# How to styled image in pointStyle ChartJs

Tags: javascript, image, chart.js, styles

How is to put image to pointstyle and add rounded coloured border around it (or any shape around img with coloured border)? I manage to add image to pointstyle, but can't style it. Really appreciate any help!
My code:

```
    const img = new Image(30, 30);
    img.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStkCgp2U1hHVVtWcf_SD4tVyLqA49lhgygEed0PPPKOZxcevudk3NZ1trGyhpAAMIJysc&usqp=CAU';
    
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'First Dataset',
        data: [{
          x: 20,
          y: 30,
          
        }],
        pointStyle: img,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
      }]
    };

const config = {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: data,
  options: {}
};
```

Comment: You can either make your image how you need it before loading it in your js, other approach is to make a second canvas, put the image on there, draw anything you want extra and pass that canvas for the pointStyle.

Comment: Thanlsks for your reply! Is it possible to overridden the draw method of the chartJS?

Comment: Yes, you can extend chart typed and adjust the draw: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/charts.html

Comment: Thanks! Help a newbie please!) Im sufferind for several days. Can you write in detail? preferable with code?  thanks alot for helping!